# \spacedlowsmallcaps in caption label

Tags: formatting, captions

How i can make the `labelfont` also in `\spacedlowsmallcaps` in addition to sans serif and small ?

```
\documentclass{article}

            \usepackage{microtype}
            \usepackage{caption}

            \microtypesetup{expansion=false}%

            \DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%

            \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwona}


\captionsetup{%
             format=hang,%
             labelfont={small,sf},%
             font={small,sf},%
             width={.8\textwidth}%
             }

\captionsetup[table]{skip=\medskipamount}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

`\subfloat` command

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mysublabel}{\small\sffamily\bothIfSecond{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{~}\spacedlowsmallcaps{(#2)}}

\captionsetup[subfloat]{%
                       labelformat=mysublabel,%
                       labelsep=space,%
                       listofformat=subparens,%
                       font={small,sf},%
                   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare your own labelformat. The `caption` package provides `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` for that. It takes two arguments, the name and the code. Inside the code argument you can use `#1` for the caption name (like “Figure” or “Table”) and `#2` for the number. To get the right formatting even if one of these is not provided the `caption` package also defines `\bothIfFirst` and `\bothIfSecond` which typeset both their arguments if the respective argument is given and non if not. This might be important if the `subcaption` package is used. For details please refer to the [package documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcase}

\microtypesetup{expansion=false}%

\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwona}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mycaption}{%
  \bothIfFirst{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{~}\spacedlowsmallcaps{#2}}

\captionsetup{%
             format=hang,%
             % labelfont={small,sf},% not necessary since `font' applies to both label and text
             labelformat=mycaption,
             font={small,sf},%
             width={.8\textwidth}%
             }

\captionsetup[table]{skip=\medskipamount}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks but this cancel the numeration, how can I fix that?

Comment: @FormlessCloud see my edited answer

Comment: good ! could you check my updated question with the settings of the subfloat command, if that settings are correct?

Comment: I'm unsure about your use of `\bothIfSecond`. Do you really want to use argument `#1` only if argument `#2` is used? Shouldn't that be `\bothIfFirst`? Other than that it looks ok to me.